# Identify capacitors in Arduino Starter Kit

Tags: arduino, identification

I have a couple of components in the Arduino Starter Kit that I'm not able to find the specs for, this is a picture of them (ruler in cm for scale):

[image]

It's probably not possible to read the labels on them, so I'll write them down: The blue ones say

```
µ1J63
?1E6
```

Where the ? represents a celltower-like symbol.

And the orange ones say

```
101
Suntan *
```

The manual mentions that they are capacitors but doesn't say anything about them. The online [starter kit page](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoStarterKit) only mentions one capacitor type and that one wasn't even included.

Comment: "Where the ? represents a celltower-like symbol." => This is the logo of the company Epcos

Comment: @rels Thanks for removing that last bit of uncertainty!

Answer (score 9):

> µ1J63

0.1µF, ±5% tolerance, 63WV max

> 101

10E1(100)pF (0.1nF), no precision or working voltage given

[All About Capacitor Markings](http://web.archive.org/web/20200811104212/http://www.robotoid.com/appnotes/electronics-capacitor-markings.html)

As an aside, I don't believe you have an authentic kit there since the contents don't match the manifest.

Comment: Thanks! I think I do actually have the official kit, as I bought it in a legit store, it came in the standard box and it included the Arduino Projects Book. Maybe I have an older version (~2 years ago) then the one the site describes.

Answer (score 0):

Suntan might be:
Suntan TS15001H101KSBSA0R 100pF 10% 50V SL 2.5mm Ceramic Disc Capacitor

Comment: Usually 101 = 100pF. | 1E6 = 1000000 = 1 million picofarad = 1 uF. | Usually